# Bing maps Ajax Control vs Silverlight Control

Tags: ajax, silverlight, bing-maps

I'm doing research on what kind of technology to use for a web application where the map is quite the important factor. It will be database driven and there will be a lot of customisation to make the control look more conform with the rest of the application's graphics.

Bing maps really seems to promote the Bing Maps Ajax Control with very little mention on the Silverlight control. I normally follow advice from the technology provider, but since I'm way more comfortable with Silverlight then with script languages I'm hesitating.

Why is Microsoft pushing the Ajax control? What are, next to the fact Silverlight is a plugin etc., the advantages of using Ajax. My gut tells me the Silverlight control will look smoother and have more customisation options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having used both and trying to keep on top of ever-changing trends, here's my take on it:

If you want maximum compatibility across browsers and platforms, including tablets or phones then you will want to to use the AJAX control. However, if that's not a concern, i.e. your audience can use the Silverlight plug-in and you're not worried about reaching everybody, the Silverlight control has far higher performance. IMO, it is also easier to code and create usable interfaces for...but that is because I've coded in XAML/C# long enough to understand most of it. By easier, I mean having far more control over appearance and behavior. That even applies to HTML5 because the tools are not near as good...yet. If you need to superimpose vectors (lines, polygons, esp. multipart polygons) then you just about have to use something like Silverlight to get the performance.

Why is MS pushing AJAX over Silverlight? Because they want to reach iOS devices and Android devices that don't support Flash (most of them) and by the same token, Silverlight. They also want to grab developer mindshare from those who don't see the *beauty* in XAML/C# programming. So to recap, consider your audience and performance requirements. Unless you really need copious vector overlays, the AJAX control will be your better bet.

Comment: I already made up my mind and chose the silverligh control for my application. This answer has kinda confirmed my choice and has added information I was not aware of yet. Thanks